# Anti forgery token jquery ajax with asp .net core

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core

I am doing an ajax request with jQuery that sends it to an asp .net core controller. I send the request along with the anti forgery token like this:

```
    $('#btnSyncDictionary').click(function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "HealthPanel/SyncDictionary",
        headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() }
    });

    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The thing is that it only works for the first ajax call. Subsequent ajax calls fail the anti forgery validation for the asp .net core controller.

Why does this happen? I think I might need to update the token after each request.

Comment: Could you share more details about your view and SyncDictionary action?

Comment: Hi @Alecu,did you still have problems?Could you share more details that could reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

**TestMiddleware.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace Test.Middleware
{
    public class TestMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        public TestMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, AppDbContext dataContext, UserManager<User> userManager, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            SetAntiForgeryTokenCookie();
            // Move forward into the pipeline
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
        private void SetAntiForgeryTokenCookie(HttpContext httpContext, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(httpContext);
            httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
        }
    }
    public static class TestMiddlewareExtensions
    {
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseTestMiddleware(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            return builder.UseMiddleware<TestMiddleware>();
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Test.Middleware;

namespace Test
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database"), b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Test")));

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;
                // Lockout settings
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
                // User settings
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(480);
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
            services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
            {
                // Antiforgety settings
                options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseTestMiddleware();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**script.js**

```
self.saveSurvey = function (userId) {
        var csrfToken = self.getCookie("CSRF-TOKEN");
        var ajaxUrl = "Account/Save",
            ajaxData = {
                UserId: userId
            };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: JSON.stringify(ajaxData),
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": csrfToken
            },
            success: function (viewModel) {
                console.log("Eureka!")
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Not Eureka!")
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Where is SetAntiForgeryTokenCookie() being called in this example?